# WCF Data Service gives 404 when making OData requests for derived types

Tags: inheritance, wcf-data-services, odata

I think I'm missing a trick getting WCF data services/OData/Inheritance working; I've created a couple of simple tables:

```
create table Super 
(
superID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null PRIMARY KEY, 
supername nvarchar(55),
)


create table sub
(
superID int not null,
extraData nvarchar(100),
FOREIGN KEY (superID) REFERENCES Super(superID)
)


insert Super values('abc')
insert Super values('def')
insert Super values('ghi')
insert Super values('jkl')
insert Super values('mno')


insert sub values(1, 'pqrstu')
insert sub values(3, 'vwxyz')
```

Pulled them into an edmx, replaced the relationship auto created with an inheritance one, which generates:

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
#region Contexts

public partial class Entities : ObjectContext
    {        ....    }

#endregion

#region Entities

[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="Model", Name="sub")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class sub : Super
    {
    #region Factory Method
    ...
    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String extraData
    ...

    #endregion

    }


[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="Model", Name="Super")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(sub))]
public partial class Super : EntityObject
    {
    #region Factory Method
    ...

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties


    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 superID
    ...


    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String supername
    ...

    #endregion

    }

#endregion

}
```

set up the service to use V3:

```
namespace WebApplication3
    {
    public class WcfDs : DataService<Entities>
        {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
            {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
            }
        }
    }
```

Querying the Supers works fine :

```
http://localhost:8384/WcfDs.svc/Supers
```

I've tried a host of URLs in a vain attempt to get the derived types:

```
http://localhost:8384/WcfDs.svc/Supers/Model.sub/
http://localhost:8384/WcfDs.svc/Supers(1)/Model.sub/
http://localhost:8384/WcfDs.svc/Supers/WebApplication3.sub/
http://localhost:8384/WcfDs.svc/Supers(1)/WebApplication3.sub/
....
```

but I always get a 404 Resource not found response. What am I missing?

Comment: So, `/Supers(1)` works (and is of the `sub` type), but `/Supers(1)/<type-name>` doesn't? In the result you're getting for `/Supers(1)`, assuming it's ATOM, there should be an xml element called `category`. What is the value of the `term` name of the `category` element? That value should be the full type name of the entity. For example, for `http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)`, you can see the type name is `ODataDemo.Product`.

Comment: correct,  /Supers(1) works and /Supers(1)/Model.sub does not. The category element for /supers(1) is: <category term="Model.sub" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />

Answer (score 3):

And the trick is:

Switch from using the Visual Studio Development server to use the Local IIS in the project properties.

At least, this worked in my VS 2010 environment.

Comment: Yes - that would do it :-)
The VS Dev server has problem with URLs which contain the dot character. It will effectively return 404 or 400 for that without the URL ever getting to be processed by the WCF DS. Using Local IIS or the Express IIS solves this problem (as you've just found out). Sorry I didn't realize this could be happening before.